# mangled terminal output after failing emacsclient / folding mode launch

Tags: code-folding, emacs-daemon

I consistently get the following problem on Emacs 24.5.1 with `folding` package (version `20140401.3`) for which I've found a workaround but would like to understand what was going on.

As you can see in the screenshot above, the emacs server started OK, but when I try to launch the `emacsclient` it just hangs there:

[image]

… after killing `emacsclient` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I get into a situation where nothing is echoed on my terminal as I type a command and, moreover, the command's output is mangled (line feed characters are apparently missing):
[image]

Upon further investigation I noticed that this behaviour was dependent on the type of file I was trying to open with `emacsclient`. Some files triggered it, some not. Further digging pointed me to a message emitted by the `folding` package (version `20140401.3`) when I was trying to open the offending files.

The message on the mini-buffer read:

> Folding error: mode is not in `folding-mode-marks-alist'

Upon adding the single line marked as "line-A" in my `.emacs` the problem went away:

```
(use-package folding
  :ensure t
  :config
  (folding-install-hooks)
  (defun my-always-fold ()
    (setq-local folded-file t))
  (advice-add #'folding-mode-find-file :before #'my-always-fold)
  (folding-add-to-marks-list 'json-mode "foo" "foo") ;; line-A
  )
```

However, even without the fix, directly opening the file using `emacs` (not `emacsclient`) does not result in this behaviour. Something a lot milder happens: the file is not placed in the buffer that's currently opened. Instead I am presented with the `*scratch*` buffer and the file I asked to open is placed in another buffer. This is what I see when I press `C-x C-b`:

[image]

… so I just use `C-x C-b` and navigate to my buffer to bring it up. And there is no mangling at all at the terminal. This leds me to believe that the problem may also be related to emacs daemon / emacsclient.

My questions are:

1. was this problem related to `emacsclient` or `folding` mode ?
2. how is it possible for `emacsclient` to mangle my terminal's output even after it's killed and how could I have fixed the terminal output?
3. is there another way to solve this problem? I don't want to have to specify folding marks for JSON files because folding makes no sense in JSON.

Comment: I can provide some minor input for #2: Emacs can set various terminal capabilities in order to do various things, such as enabling line wrapping. If Emacs is killed, these settings *may* not be restored, leaving your terminal with possibly broken settings. You can however reset the terminal capabilities with certain commands, e.g., `stty sane`

Comment: @Xaldew I reproduced the problem and can confirm that `stty sane` addresses that symptom.